# Graph - Theory : Connection between nodes at same level

Tags: java, graph

In a graph i need to find whether any two nodes at same level are directly connected or not.

I have applied following implementation.

Find the level of each node and store it in an array.
Traverse each Node N1 and check all of its direct connections.
if any of the nodes have same level as the node N1
return true

I am new to algorithms. I have no idea on finding the "loop invariant" or correctness of the algorithm. How do i proceed? Is there any better implementation?

Comment: Please post the code that you have so far toward your solution, and add the language you're using to program it in your tags.

Comment: What is exactly "level of a node"?

Comment: As lexicore stated, you need to fully define your question.  We don't know what a level is.

Comment: @Orch I guess it's the length of the shortest path from some node, but I'd like to hear what OP says.

Comment: I am sorry for late reply. By level i mean the the distance from root node. I have arbitrarily selected a node from graph as root node. Root node is at level 0. The shortest distance from root to any other node is the level of that node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically just do a bfs, and store nodes in a hash table with their corresponding level as you visit them.  Each time you visit a node, check to see if it's in the table, if not, add it to the table with its level which you keep track of by a counter.
When you check the edges of each of the nodes you can check to see if the the node it links to has the same level as the node you are currently at, if so return true.  If you complete your bfs without finding any nodes at the same level, return false.

Comment: Thanks. I was doing the same with arrays. Now, i use hashtable.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it answers your question.